# How to make an internal Java package accessible in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, legacy-code, java-11

I have a legacy Java (8) project opened in Eclipse with Java 11 (or Java 10). Eclipse is now rightly complaining about inaccessible packages. E.g. `com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI`.

When compiling from command line I can make those packages  accessible explicitly by adding a parameter to `javac`:

`--add-exports java.desktop/com.apple.laf=ALL-UNNAMED`

Is there a way to do the same from inside the Eclipse IDE? I tried to add an accessible rule on the JDK library. But that seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

And yes, I know, we should migrate the project to use only official APIs. But that's a long, long way...

Comment: UIManager.createLookAndFeel is a useful way to get a reference to the built-in look and feels.

Comment: @AlanBateman how do you get the necessary name for `UIManager.createLookAndFeel`? I only know `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`, which is suitable for `UIManager.setLookAndFeel`, but `createLookAndFeel` seems to expect the “name” rather than class name…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, since I found a solution.

1. In Eclipse settings navigate to: *Java Build Path* → *Libraries* → *Modulepath* → *JRE System Library*
2. Expand it and double click on: *Is modular (modifies encapsulation)*
3. Switch to *Details* tab
4. Add a new export: E.g. *java.desktop* → *com.apple.laf*

Comment: I had same issue but fixed in a different way. On step 3, stay in "Contents" tab, then find the relevant library in the "Implicitly included modules" box, select it, then click the up arrow button to move it into "Explicitly included modules" box. For me, I had to do this with `java.naming` in order to import classes in `javax.naming`)

Comment: actually disregard what i said above... that got it to compile, but then i got errors at runtime. ultimately for me it turned out to be because i had updated jdk version for the build, but tomcat was still using old jdk version when launching

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I have the module `lwjgl.jar` in the project's `lib/jars` folder, and I'm trying `import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;` and getting the same inaccessible message -- This answer looks like the closest I can find, but I'm confused at what export to make. What do I enter in the `Source module` and `Package` fields? it doesn't seem to recognize `lwjgl` or anything else I've tried.

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to include the line `requires lwjgl;` in my `module-info.java` file :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup problem severity. This falls under `forbidden reference (access rules)` under `Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help. For the reference: The error message in Eclipse is "The type com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI is not accessible".

Comment: Please check it out again. I tried it out on a clean project before I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/601) you can add the parameters passed with javac in command line to Eclipse with these steps:

- Click on `Run->Run Configurations`.
- In the window that appeared under `Main tab` `Browse the project` and the `Main class` for which you want to pass the arguments.
- Now click on the `Arguments` tab.
- In the text-box labeled `Program arguments:`, type `${string_prompt}`
- Click on `Apply and Close`.

Now when you run your Java application a prompt will appear. You can add all your arguments separated with space here.

Comment: Those arguments are not passed to the java compiler, but to the java runtime (java). Hence, they only influence your application during execution. They have no effect on the built in compiler in the IDE.