# Error: The package org.apache.commons is not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons

I have just recently started using Eclipse and am running into problems trying to install external libraries. Following online tutorials, I add the `.jar` file to the classpath and I see it in the referenced libraries folder. Despite this, when trying to import, I get the error:

The package org.apache.commons is not accessible

[image: Error]

For reference, I am trying to install the apache math commons library.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343704/how-to-make-an-internal-java-package-accessible-in-eclipse

Comment: Eclipse is not recognizing libraries which is causing errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code probably has two issues.

First, the import statement is wrong since in Java you cannot add a package itself, but all classes of a package as follows (note `.*;` at the end):

```
import org.apache.commons.math4.linear.*;
```

or a specific class, e.g.

```
import org.apache.commons.math4.linear.FieldMatrix;
```

Second, you use the [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) by having a `module-info.java` file in the default package probably without the required `requires <module>;` statement. JPMS was introduced in Java 9 and you have Java 12.

Do one of the following:

- **Delete the `module-info.java` file** (if needed, you can recreate it via right-clicking the project folder and choosing *Configure > Create module-info.java*)
- **In `module-info.java` add** the corresponding **`requires` statement**, e.g. by going to the line with the `import` statement and using the corresponding *Quick Fix* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks. This seemed to fix the issue along with adding apache math to the module path rather than the class path.

Comment: Thanks for the module-info tip, just adding the archive was not working. Delete /Update module-info fixed :)