# The type org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer is not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lucene

i am searching for a while now to fix this issue, i am trying to use Lucene for my java assignment in Eclipse and as you can see i have imported the .jar files that have the classes in the referenced libraries, the code i use is use by my professor and he told me its not old and it workds in his machine, where is my mistake?
Thank you

[Eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKfBt.png)

Comment: You have a module-info.java so you are using the new Java module system which requires extra information. Delete the module-info.java to use the 'traditional' system.

Comment: @greg-449 i did deleted the tab , but no change

Comment: Delete the file `module-info.java`. See here the second point for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62058336/6505250