# The org. package in eclipse is not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm trying to write a selenium code in java using eclipse. However, the IDE shows that "The org package is not accessible", as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Eclipse should be suggesting a quick fix for this issue in the details of the error message. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056713/error-the-package-org-apache-commons-is-not-accessible

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a Build tool Like Maven or Gradle.

Instead of using a physical path you may use build tool like Maven with below dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

if using gradle then below dependency

```
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
```