# The package org.openqa.selenium is not accessible

Tags: java, selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;  
  
public class First {  
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        
    // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables  
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");  
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();  
      
    // Launch website  
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com/");  
          
    // Click on the search text box and send value  
    driver.findElement(By.id("input")).sendKeys("javatpoint tutorials");  
          
    // Click on the search button  
     
      
    }  
  
}
```

This is the problem I m having the library is not accessible even though I installed and configured coorectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343704/how-to-make-an-internal-java-package-accessible-in-eclipse

Comment: it is still showing some error can you help me with that?

Comment: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\AAKASH\Downloads\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module

Answer (score 0):

try creating a class in the src folder under no specific package. worked for me.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: What _src_ folder are you referring to? I also agree with the other [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647080/the-package-org-openqa-selenium-is-not-accessible/78175372#comment137821702_78175372). Don't post comments as answers just because you do not yet have enough reputation to post comments. I suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help] in order to understand how this website works.